# Stream sound from android application to a device over wifi

Tags: java, android

I am building an android music player that can stream all the sound generated by my app to an external IP rather than playing it to speaker/headset over wifi.

Basically I want to route all the sound output of my app to an external IP rather than phone's speaker, bluetooth speaker or earphones.

I have read about udp , upnp and rtp. Help me figure out which class I should use, i shall only be streaming audio (locally stored or from other providers as spotify or pandora).

Comment: This is _way_ to broad to ask here.  Narrow it down to a specific question and try again.

Comment: @iamkrillin: I am a beginner and trying to figure this out. I am making a android music player which has to stream all sound generated by the application to an external receiver rather than from speaker. I have to achieve this over wifi rather than bluetooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a provision for this using the `AudioStream` class; this class lets you create an audio-based RTSP stream. Since you are planning on using this over Wi-Fi, as long as the device from which you are trying to access the audio is on the same Wi-Fi network, then you should be able to receive the audio. More information regarding this class may be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream.html

Also, I have included the link to a github project that should help you get started: https://github.com/apotoxin/VideoProject/blob/master/android/spydroid-ipcamera/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/audio/GenericAudioStream.java

Comment: i tried looking up for more info, i found a way to send data from mic to an external IP in same network. How do i make my music player transfer all the sound to that IP ?